# how do you get the target of an attribute error programatically?

Tags: python

I want to do something like:

```
class Foo:
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'an instance of Foo'

try:
    print(Foo().baz)
except AttributeError as err:
    print('target:', err.target)
    print('name:', err.name)
```

and get an output of

```
target: an instance of Foo
name: baz
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, AttributeError does not carry this information in a useful way. You have two options:

1. Parse the message with a regex like `r"object has no attribute '([^']+)'"`; or
2. use `getattr` to access the variable through a string: `varname = 'baz'; print getattr(Foo(), varname)`. That way, you can just examine the contents of `varname`.

Comment: well, that kinda sucks. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you control writing the class, make a custom exception:

```
class CustomAttributeError(Exception):
    def __init__(self,object,attribute):
        self.object = object
        self.attribute = attribute
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} has no attribute '{}'".format(self.object,self.attribute)

class Foo(object):
    def __getattr__(self,n):
        raise CustomAttributeError(self,n)


a = Foo()
b = Foo()
c = Foo()

a.x=1
b.x=1

try:
    a.x
    b.x
    c.x
except CustomAttributeError as e:
    # Catch this missing attribute and give it a value
    print e
    setattr(e.object,e.attribute,5)

print c.x
```

#### Output

```
<x.Foo object at 0x031478D0> has no attribute 'x'
5
```